# Rails db:migrate gets 'stuck'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im using rails 3.0.1, when I run `rake db:migrate` it runs all the pending migrations and seem to get "stuck" in the end, when I go to the db (MySql) during that time and run `show processlist` I see that the db is performing `SHOW KEYS FROM` for each table in the DB and thats whats hanging the migrate process.

any ideas how to avoid that?

Comment: Anything special you do there? Or just simple generating of tables and columns?

Comment: What is the last migration works before the migration process gets stuck? Try removing the one after that and see if that helps. Maybe your last migration is the problem for some reason.

Comment: the pending migration just creates a couple of tables.

Comment: @PazAricha changed the order, still same behaviour

Comment: @PazAricha the last migration creates a new table, nothing special about it...

Comment: how many migrations do you have. Do you have alot of data in your tables? If so and if they're indexed, that may cause the "stuck" or slow down.

Comment: @lsaffie about 4 migrations, all creating new tables so its not indexing...

Comment: it'd be useful to see the migrations. If you have no data in there, I would drop the db and recreate the entire db. If the problem still persists, I would comment out the code from all migrations and leave only the first one uncommented. Then do rake db:migrate migration by migration. That way you'll know which one is the faulty one. There may be something weird now with the state. Dropping it would clear that concern. rake db:drop; rake db:create; rake db:migrate

Answer (score -3):

I'm putting my last comment as an answer for better formatting. Also, I believe this qualifies as an answer rather than a comment.

it'd be useful to see the migrations. If you have no data in there, I would drop the db and recreate the entire db.
If the problem still persists, I would comment out the code from all migrations and leave only the first one uncommented.

Then run the migrations one by one. That way you'll know which one is the faulty one.

Lastly, there may be something weird with the state. Dropping the db would clear that concern.

```
rake db:drop; rake db:create; rake db:migrate
```

I would probably do that first to start fresh.